# Error while trying to install package dplyr in RSTUDIO

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

I'm  trying to install dplyr package in my RSTUDIO environment and getting below error.

```
 install.packages("dplyr")
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6:
  cannot open URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/PACKAGES'
```

The same URL is manually accessible.

Comment: have tried looking at this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa

Comment: yeaa have tried the same, still no luck